# JavaScript executor - passing single quote character throws "Unexpected identifier"

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, groovy

I want to pass the below value in the script using the javascript executor.

```js
String value = "ac.saveDocket('CompanyRegistration','https://yyy.yyy',0);"
```

```java
JavascriptExecutor executor = ((driver) as JavascriptExecutor)
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class=\'CodeMirror-code\']/div[1]//pre"))
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML='$value';", webElement)
```

This results in the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Unexpected identifier
```

Execution is successful without special characters so the problem is definitely with the single quotes.

How I can pass special characters like single quotes to the JavaScript executor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on browser console:

```
arguments[0].innerHTML='ac.saveDocket(\'CompanyRegistration\',\'https://yyy.yyy\',0);'
```

And for java code use like this:

```
String value = "ac.saveDocket(\\'CompanyRegistration\\',\\'https://yyy.yyy\\',0);";

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your_xpath"));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

executor.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML='"+value+"'", element);
```